# Auto add Title to Link in CKEditor 5

Tags: ckeditor

We use CKeditor 5 and would like to have a functionality that the title of an address in the editor is automatically added to the title.

I don't mean the browser functionality (like the stuff everyone hates in Edge), but preferably CKEditor sends a Get query in the background and reads out the title of the address.

- Urls should use the content of <title>
- Mail Addresses should be covered too, if possible.

We currently use AutoLink, but we dont see any functionality for that.
Is there something built-in or do we have to write a plugin for that?